# How would I number the items on my list out when I print them?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am redoing an assignment I have not gotten a perfect score on and I seem to not understand how to label my list with numbers, also trying to print it on the same line.

I've tried adding numbers into my list so categorize but that it was not my mentor wants. She is asking for me number the items in the list using a for loop counter.

```
games = ["Super Mario Maker 2", "Bayonetta 3", "Dark Souls 4", "Astral Chain", "Persona 5 Royale"]

for n in range(0, len(games)):
    print("Game: " + games[n])
```

Currently this prints out everything in the list from star to finish. It starts out with Game: (1st item in list) and so forth. I'm trying to figure out how to label these as they go forth so that it would print something like `Game 1: (1st item), Game 2: (2nd item)` and so forth, printing everything on a single line with commas in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add n to the output.

```
for n in range(0, len(games)): 
    print("Game {}: {}".format(n, games[n]))
```

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please mark it as a solution. Thank you!

Comment: That actually won't work, because you can't add a str to and int

Comment: This will not write them to a single line.

Answer (score 2):

With `enumerate`:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(games): 
      print('{}: {}'.format(idx, val))
# Out:
# Game 0: Super Mario Maker 2
# Game 1: Bayonetta 3
# Game 2: Dark Souls 4
# Game 3: Astral Chain
# Game 4: Persona 5 Royale
```

Or using the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) option `start`:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(games, start=1): 
    print('{}: {}'.format(idx, val))
# Out:
# Game 1: Super Mario Maker 2
# Game 2: Bayonetta 3
# Game 3: Dark Souls 4
# Game 4: Astral Chain
# Game 5: Persona 5 Royale
```

In one line:

```
print(*['Game {}: {}'.format(i, v) for i,v in enumerate(games, start=1)], sep='\n')
```

Comment: I'm a bit new to python, but what exactly is "enumerate"? I've read that it loops over things and has an automatic counter but I'm not sure exactly what that translates to.

Comment: @RUSSELLYANG `enumerate` is an object that will feed you tuples `(count, item)` as you iterate over it, where `count` is an `int` and `item` is the current element in the iterable, coming from `enumerate(iterable)`. You can see examples [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/)

Comment: This will not write them to a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate`:

```
for counter, value in enumerate(some_list):
    print(counter, value)
```

So, for your example:

```
for i, game in enumerate(games):
   print("Game {0}: {1}".format(i+1, game))
```

For Python 3.6 or later:

```
for i, game in enumerate(games):
    print(f"Game {i + 1}: {game}")
```

As you can also see, f-strings are very useful and come in handy for what you're trying to do!

**EDIT:** printing as a single line:

```
print(', '.join([f"Game {i + 1}: {game}" for i, game in enumerate(games)]))
```

Comment: This will not write them to a single line.

Answer (score 1):

You can print all items on a list using join and format string based on the index of each item in the list.

```
', '.join(f'Game {i+1}: {games[i]}' for i in range(len(games)))
```

Result:

```
'Game 1: Super Mario Maker 2, Game 2: Bayonetta 3, Game 3: Dark Souls 4, Game 4: Astral Chain, Game 5: Persona 5 Royale'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually really simple, you can just use:

- [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) with the optional `start` argument to get the indexes starting from 1
- a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to loop over the values of the list
- an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to insert the variables to a string
- [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to concatenate the elements to one string with commas in between

```
games = ["Super Mario Maker 2", "Bayonetta 3", "Dark Souls 4", "Astral Chain", "Persona 5 Royale"]

print(', '.join(f'Game {i}: {game}' for i, game in (enumerate(games, start=1))))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Game 1: Super Mario Maker 2, Game 2: Bayonetta 3, Game 3: Dark Souls 4, Game 4: Astral Chain, Game 5: Persona 5 Royale
> ```

Answer (score -1):

add this after game in the string

```
str(n+1)
```

so it should be like this

```
'game '+str(n+1) +' rest of the string'
```

Comment: For this to be a valid answer it really should be little bit more complete.